# Does any yogic siddhi let a human to be simultaneously present at two different places physically?

Tags: yoga, siddhi

Is there any yogic siddhi by help of which one can be present at two or more places physically at the same time?

Comment: Yes [Ashta Maha Siddhis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siddhi) [Saubhari Rishi, who took 50 bodies simultaneously](http://bhagavata.org/canto9/chapter6.html)

Comment: @ram I do not see any proof for that in your link. Please explain.

Answer (score 3):

I have read about a saint who was able to be at two places at the same time in Paramhansa Yogananda's book "Autobiography of a Yogi". There is a chapter named as "The Saint with Two Bodies. But i don't know in particular how that can be achieved.

Comment: Welcome! You can mention more info about that saint from relevant chapters of the book. Please also visit [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/3500).

Comment: Is the following book helpful in finding the exact details? https://www.holybooks.com/wp-content/uploads/Autobiography-of-a-Yogi-by-Paramahansa-Yogananda.pdf

Comment: this book has mentioned different yogis and their different powers. But since it is an autobiography , ways to achieve those things are not mentioned. You can read about different yogis such as gandh baba who can generate fragrance, or a yogi lady who can only live on air and many more. You will also learn about the paramhansa yogananda as a yogi.